# Override action bar share button onClick

Tags: android, android-intent, android-actionbar, shareactionprovider

I'm setting up a share button using the onCreateOptionsMenu and ActionShareProvider.

I setup the initial intent at onCreate but I'm looking for a way the update the ShareActionProvider intent (refresh intent EXTRA) when user clicks the share icon on the activity actionBar also . Is it possible to override this onClick function?

My onCreateOptionMenu code:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_shopping_list, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);

    mShareActionProvider = new ShareActionProvider(ctx);
    item.setActionProvider(mShareActionProvider);

    if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(mShareIntent);
    }

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Initial onCreate setup code:

```
mShareIntent = new Intent();
    mShareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    mShareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    mShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareList());
```

My refresh intent code (I want to add this to the share onClick function):

```
mShareIntent.removeExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
mShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareList());
```

Any help appreciated.